# Combining tables in R

Tags: r, tables

I have multiple tables as the output of a regression analysis.
Does anybody know how to combine these multiple tables with each other ?
The tables are all the same, the only thing that changes is the dependent variable at the top.

Does this work for regression analysis tables as well as t-test tables ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should not be a problem to combine the tables. Depending what you want to do with the combined dataframe, one possibility could be the following:

- Append one column to each single dataframe which indicates the dependent variable. For example, use mutate(DV = Dependent_variable_1)
- next, use a simple rbind command to bind the tables.

Comment: Thank you very much :)